# MVC pros and cons in terms of web application development

Tags: model-view-controller

Wondering the pros and cons for MVC architecture in terms of web application development? And What is the difference between MVC and 3-tire architecture?

Comment: **[You might have missed this, right.....](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Sarfraz [Wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675980/mvc-pros-and-cons-in-terms-of-web-application-development) is a good starting point for this type of question.

To answer your specific question about the difference between MVC and 3-tier architecture, you need to first understand that MVC is (primarily) a GUI/User-Interface framework and design pattern.

In other words, MVC would be just one tier in your 3-tier architecture, you would still have a "service/business logic" tier and a "persistance/database" tier.

Comment: I just read from some where:

Pro: the ability to have multiple views that rely upon a single model; same components can be used and called for use with any interface; model is self-contained and separate from the controller and the view, it is much less painful to change your data layer or business rules; presented with a number of reusable building blocks in the model and the view.

Con: have to spend a good amount of the time thinking about the way the parts of app will interact; more files to manage than you would otherwise; overkill for small applications.

Comment: Yes, that supports my answer, that `MVC` would only be a single tier in your multi-tier architecture.